# Polytime Computable Distribution vs Polytime Sampleable Distribution

Tags: cc.complexity-theory

Many texts on average case complexity claim:

1) Any polytime computable distribution is also polytime sampleable.

2) A polytime sampleable distribution is one where a polytime probabilistic TM generates the distribution on input 1^n.

Now, suppose we have a distribution, where

Prob(0) = 1/3
Prob(1) = 2/3.

Clearly, this distribution is polytime computable. Most texts would this claim that it's also polytime sampleable. However, I don't see how any polytime probabilistic TM can generate the above distribution. [I see how expected polytime proabilistic TM can generate this distribution; but that is not the same as polytime probabilistic TM.]

Question: Where am I going wrong? Am I misunderstanding polytime sampleable, or polytime computable? The distribution defined above, is it

(1) NOT polytime computable (i.e. writing out 1/3 would take an infinite number of bits) 
or
(2) It is actually polytime sampleable; since in reality, we only require that the algorithm run in *expected* polytime?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you add the definitions of "polytime computable" and "polytime sampleable" according to one of the textbooks that claims the equivalence? That might make it easier to answer the question.